# nodejs i don't know why post is not linked

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
1.app_file.js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.set('views','./views');
app.set('view engine','pug');
app.get('/web/1', function(req, res){
  res.render('new');
})
app.post('/www',function(req, res){
  res.send('i like film'); <--
})
app.listen(3000,function(){
  console.log('Connected, 3000port');
});

 2new.pug

html
 head
    body
     form(action='/web' method='post')
     p
     input(type='text' name ='title' placeholder='title')
     p
      textarea(name='description')
     p
      input(type='submit')enter code here
```

i want make website for my diary
so i am use nodejs and html but it so hard i don't know what to do for success

Comment: `action='/web'` but in express you are using `app.post('/www'`...they don't match

Comment: thank  but I just fixed that part, but it's not connecting.

Comment: what are you getting as a response when you submit?

Comment: app.post('/web',function(req, res){
  res.send('i like film');
})

Comment: No, I mean in the browser what are you getting when you submit your form?

Answer (score 0):

You need to catch post data, to do that you need this line to be the first line after you declare `app`

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // this
app.set('views','./views');
```

Then you can `console.log('post', req.body)`

Answer (score 0):

Use  const router = express.Router(); for post request in express and use like this

```
   router.post('/web', (req, res) => {
           if (!err) {
                 res.send('i like film');
            }else{
                 console.log(error);
            }
           });
      // In Your Code 

     1.app_file.js
      var express = require('express');
       var app = express();
       var router = express.Router();
       app.use('', router);
       app.set('views','./views');
       app.set('view engine','pug');
        router.get('/web/1', function(req, res){
             res.render('new');
         })
         router.post('/web',function(req, res){
             console.log('success');
             res.send('i like film'); <--
          })
         app.listen(3000,function(){
             console.log('Connected, 3000port');
         });
       // Also check your terminal

       2new.pug

       html
         head
           body
              form(action='/web' method='post')
              p
              input(type='text' name ='title' placeholder='title')
              p
              textarea(name='description')
              p
              input(type='submit')enter code here
```